# Is it possible for two respectively closed systems to be entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

*Is it possible for two respectively closed systems to be entangled?*

I was thinking something along the lines of,

- We have a 2-qubit system, prepared in e.g. a Bell state.
- Each qubit is carried off to a different laboratory, and their respective systems can be described by their own local Hamiltonian. Each qubit can evolve unitarily in its respective system.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible if the systems start in an entangled state, and no measurements are performed on either subsystem.

The evolution of each closed system is described by its Hamiltonian $H_A, H_B$, with the global Hamiltonian given by
$$ H = H_A \otimes \mathbb{I}_B + \mathbb{I}_A \otimes H_B .$$

$$ U(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H_A t} \otimes \mathbb{I}_B + \mathbb{I}_A \otimes \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H_B t}  .$$

Of course this cannot *create* entanglement between $A$ and $B$. If the system starts in a product state $|\psi_0\rangle = |\psi_0^A\rangle|\psi_0^B\rangle$, it will remain in a product state at all times
$$ |\psi(t)\rangle = U(t)|\psi_0\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H_A t} |\psi_0^A\rangle\otimes \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H_B t} |\psi_0^B\rangle .$$

On the other hand, if the initial state $|\psi_0\rangle$ is entangled, under unitary time evolution it will remain in general non-factorisable. Subsystem $A$ can be described as an isolated system with Hamiltonian $H_A$ and initial mixed state $\rho_A(0) = \mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|)$. Its time evolution is given by
$$ \rho_A(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H_A t} \rho_A(0) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}H_A t}.$$

Its purity is time-independent,
$$ \mathrm{tr}[ \rho_A(t)^2] =\mathrm{tr} \left[\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H_A t} \rho_A(0)^2 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}H_A t}\right] = \mathrm{tr}\left[ \rho_A(0)^2\right], $$
therefore the state will remain mixed, and the two subsystems entangled.

#### Applications

This is an important topic in **quantum computation** and **quantum information theory**.

For example, the [quantum teleportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) protocol is based on the two parties sharing two qubits from an EPR pair, or Bell state, and each performing *local operations* on their qubit.

[image: Quantum circuit representation for teleportation of a quantum state, from Wikipedia.]

In particular, Alice performs operations that change her part of the state, without affecting Bob's state or the relative entanglement, until she *measures* her two qubits.

#### Quantum information

More generally, it is important to characterise which states can be reached by operating on each subsystem separately. This is formalised as evolution under *local operations and classical communication* ([LOCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOCC)), which roughly speaking means the separate unitary evolution described above, plus measurements and classical communication between Alice and Bob.

Studying the evolution of entanglement has been an important part of this characterisation: the basic idea is that it can only decrease under LOCC. This is quite a broad topic, and has been the subject of research for over twenty years. Starting points to read more about this include this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOCC#Entanglement_transformations), chapter 12 of Nielsen and Chuang, and the [seminal paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811053) by Nielsen.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful and informative! Just one question RE the form of your Hamiltonian - why is it a sum of tensor products and not just $H_{A}\otimes H_{B}$

Comment: @Meths (a bit of an a posteriori justification) the answer shows that what I wrote indeed describes the completely separate evolution of two independent systems if the initial state is separable. The tensor product $\tilde{H}=H_A\otimes H_B$ introduces an interaction between the two. For example with what I wrote, the ground state of the global system is just the product of the two ground states, which is not the case for $\tilde{H}$.

Comment: @Meths The tensor product would describe an interaction between the two system, with a non-factorised time evolution that creates entanglement. I have been deliberately slightly pedantic with the notation. Often one would just write $H=H_A+H_B$ and $\tilde{H}=H_AH_B$. Maybe an example clarifies this a bit: consider two spin-1/2's with $H_A =\sigma^z_A, H_B=\sigma^z_B$. You would have $H=\sigma^z_A+\sigma^z_B$ and $\tilde{H}=\sigma^z_A\sigma^z_B$, the latter being the prototypical spin-spin interaction.

Comment: thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The system as a whole evolves unitarily unless/until you make an observation.  Any observation on either qubit will disentangle the system.

Comment: Right, but the question is whether each qubit can respectively be described by its own Hamiltonian on its own state space, with unitary evolutions on this state space.

Comment: You are asking whether the system can be disentangled.  The answer is yes if you observe a qubit, no otherwise.  Pure unitary evolution cannot disentangle the system.  Proving this might be an instructive exercise.

Comment: I wasn't asking if it could be disentangled. If we trace out the second qubit, we could describe the first qubit with a density operator. All the postulates of quantum mechanics can be described in the density operator formalism.